How to remove android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and add a non-violating permission and use ( WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses ) folder in flutter
This code is working well but in this 1 permission violate google play policy so how to update my code and permission of android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
Google Play Review: If your app still needs MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, you will have to provide detailed information to Google during the app review process so how to over come this permission and add a new
This is my Android.menifest File
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:minSdkVersion="30" />


<application
    android:label="Status Saver"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>

And another file of Provider with permission and get data
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class Status extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isFetching = false;
  List<FileSystemEntity> _getVideos = [];
  List<FileSystemEntity> _getImages = [];
  final Directory _videoDir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses');

  List<FileSystemEntity> get getImages => _getImages;
  List<FileSystemEntity> get getVideos => _getVideos;

  bool _isWhatsappAvailable = false;

  bool get isWhatsappAvailable => _isWhatsappAvailable;

  void getStatus(String ext) async {
    isFetching = true;
    // notifyListeners();
    await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    final status = await Permission.storage.request();

    if (status.isDenied) {
      Permission.storage.request();
      print("Permission Denied");
      return;
    }

    if (status.isGranted) {
      if (Directory('${_videoDir.path}').existsSync()) {
        final items = _videoDir.listSync();

        if (ext == ".mp4") {
          _getVideos =
              items.where((element) => element.path.endsWith(ext)).toList();

          isFetching = false;

          notifyListeners();
        } else {
          _getImages = items.where((element) => element.path.endsWith(ext)).toList();
          isFetching = false;

          notifyListeners();
        }

        _isWhatsappAvailable = true;
        notifyListeners();

      } else {
        isFetching = false;

        print("Not whatsapp found");
        _isWhatsappAvailable = false;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
  }
}

-------------------------------------
Desing show image of .statues folder
-------------------------------------

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:status_saver/Providers/fetch_status.dart';
import 'package:status_saver/Util/Widgets/status_image_container.dart';

class PhotosTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotosTab({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final statusImages = Provider.of<Status>(context);
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 4;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black87),
      child: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () {
          statusImages.getStatus(".jpg");
          return Future.value();
        },
        child: Consumer<Status>(
          builder: (context, value, child) {
            if (statusImages.getImages.isEmpty) {
              statusImages.getStatus(".jpg");
            }
            return statusImages.isFetching
                ? const Center(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                      width: 15,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : GridView.builder(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                      mainAxisSpacing:8,
                      childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
                    ),
                    itemCount: statusImages.getImages.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return StatusImageContainer(
                        imagePath: statusImages.getImages[index].path,
                      );
                    },
                  );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I guess, We can't access the whatsapp's .status folder without using "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission because of Scoped Storage, which limits how apps can access shared storage. Apps are sandboxed to their specific directories within Android/data/ and cannot directly access other apps' data directories.

You can access the .Statuses folder using the Storage Access Framework (SAF) API, which provides privacy-friendly access.
I recommend checking out this github.com/krupal4/statusaver repo that provides a solution using SAF for the issue you mentioned. If you find it helpful, consider giving it a star!
